# Python multiprocessing - cannot exit completed processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

The following code using the multiprocessing package runs infinitely, and the resulting error message says 'child process not created':

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
data = xlrd.open_workbook("workbook.xlsx")
data_all=[]
for sheetname in data.sheet_names() :
    #read all rows in all sheets into list of lists
    sh = data.sheet_by_name(sheetname)
    for rownum in range(sh.nrows) :
        data_all.append(sh.row_values(rownum))
data_chunks=np.array_split(data_all,5)  

output=mp.Queue()
processes=[mp.Process(target=main,args=(chunk_l,)) for chunk_l in data_chunks]

#runtime
start_time = time.time()
#Run processes
for p in processes:
    p.start()

#Exit completed processes
for p in processes:
    p.join()

#Get results from output queue
results=[output.get() for p in processes]

#runtime
end_time=time.time()
```

I stopped the process after a while and it looks like it gets stuck at p.join():

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-83ace3c1f041> in <module>()
     20     #Exit completed processes
     21     for p in processes:
---> 22         p.join()
     23 
     24     #Get results from output queue

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py in join(self, timeout)
    122         assert self._parent_pid == os.getpid(), 'can only join a child process'
    123         assert self._popen is not None, 'can only join a started process'
--> 124         res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
    125         if res is not None:
    126             _children.discard(self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py in wait(self, timeout)
     49                     return None
     50             # This shouldn't block if wait() returned successfully.
---> 51             return self.poll(os.WNOHANG if timeout == 0.0 else 0)
     52         return self.returncode
     53 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py in poll(self, flag)
     27             while True:
     28                 try:
---> 29                     pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
     30                 except OSError as e:
     31                     # Child process not yet created. See #1731717
```

The main() function I'm using for processing ends with output.put to store the results produced by the given chunk of data. I'm pretty sure this is running all the way through based on print statements after output.put() that are working, which from my understanding would mean that the child process was created and run. Does anyone have any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: What is your main() function?

Comment: It also looks like you are not passing your output queue to your main() function. I'm not sure how a global variable interacts with the multiprocessing but I would suggest adding the queue as a parameter to `main()` and passing it via `args`.

Comment: My main() function transforms the chunk_l data (it's a little too lengthy to post), but  the last few lines produce a list of lists and passes it to output.put:

    `hist_co_occurance = co_occurrences(articles_lines, terms_co_occurance)`
    
    `output.put(hist_co_occurance)`
    `print("len(hist_co_occurance): "+str(len(hist_co_occurance)))`

I still get the same error unfortunately after passing the output queue to main() via args.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could produce a minimal working example. As it stands, I can't reproduce your problem, but I don't have access to your spreadsheets or your full code. Try creating a copy of your code and removing parts of the code one at a time and see how small you can make it and still reproduce the problem. Also, instead of using your excel data you can just create random numpy arrays with `np.random`.